# C++ Segmentation fault in AIX

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, aix, bjam

Hi I have written a piece of code in C++ at AIX 6 as part of my project as below:
It compiles and build properly.But getting segmentation fault on executing below lines,
"EquipmentSMU _equipmentSMU=_smuArray[i];"

I am building it with bjam and linking all libraries with -bmaxdata:0x80000000 option.
I have tried it with  export $LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA=0x80000000 before executing it but unable to solve the problem.

I have ran the same code in windows, there it runs well without having any issues.

My Code :

```
#define EQUIP_MAX_SMU_LEN 30
#define EQUIP_MAX_SMU 100
typedef struct
{
    wchar_t _smu[EQUIP_MAX_SMU_LEN+1];

} EquipmentSMU;

class Equipment
{
public:
    Equipment();
    ~Equipment();

private:
    void _AddSMU(wchar_t* smu);

private:
    EquipmentSMU _smuArray[EQUIP_MAX_SMU];
};

void Equipment::_AddSMU(wchar_t* smu)
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i < EQUIP_MAX_SMU; i++ )
    {
        EquipmentSMU _equipmentSMU=_smuArray[i];//segmentation fault coming at here
        wchar_t _tempSmu = _equipmentSMU._smu[0];
        if(_tempSmu == L'\0' )
        {
            wcsncpy( _smuArray[i]._smu, smu, EQUIP_MAX_SMU_LEN+1 );
            return;
        }
        if( wcsncmp( _smuArray[i]._smu, smu, EQUIP_MAX_SMU_LEN+1) == 0 )
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks,

Comment: What's `i` at the segfault?

Comment: it is 0.It occurs at the very beginning of the iteration.

Comment: I suspect that your `Equipment` instance is broken. How are you creating and using it?

Comment: I suspect you are allocating your `Equipment` instance as a local variable (perhaps an array ?), and this is resulting in a stack overflow. Please include the relevant part of the code.

Comment: What is the value of the `this` pointer at the line which throws the exception?

Comment: Hi Paul,
yes this instance is local.If I avoid creating this by straightway calling _smu[0] of _smuArray[i] cant solve the problem:

Say,
if(_smuArray[i]._smu[0] == L'\0' )
instead of 
EquipmentSMU _equipmentSMU=_smuArray[i];//segmentation fault coming at here
        wchar_t _tempSmu = _equipmentSMU._smu[0];
        if(_tempSmu == L'\0' )

Comment: Interesting thing is if I print _smuArray[i]._smu[0] value 
by print _smuArray[i]._smu[0] it gives me {'Q','X',0} which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting it on the stack instead of the heap and AIX is not a fan of this.

Declare a pointer *_smuArray and use it in your construtor as _smuArray = new type[i] which should allcoate it to the heap.  Don't forget to put delete[] _smuArray and _smuArray = NULL in your destructor.  I spent 3 hours last night finding this out :)

You will probably find that your code works fine as it is if you put it in main(). It is one of those goofy AIX things.